I am trying to serve my Nodejs API using nginx server blocks
My app is running on port 3000, but when try to access my endpoints via my https://site-url, the errorlogs show that i am trying to access static files and i get response from my API,can anyone help me identify the error in my markdown.
#Server blocks for incoming HTTP requests
server {
    if ($host = www.tendaafrica.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = tendaafrica.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # server block for 'tendaafrica.net', 'www.tendaafrica.net' domains
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name tendaafrica.net www.tendaafrica.net;
    # redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;




}
server {
    if ($host = api.tendaafrica.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # server block for 'api.tendaafrica.net' domain
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.tendaafrica.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
server {
    # server block for 'static.tendaafrica.net' domain
    server_name static.tendaafrica.net;
    root /var/www/tenda-main;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tendaafrica.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tendaafrica.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    # server block for all the other requests
    # this block will be a default server block listening on port 80
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    # close the connection immediately
    return 444;
}

# server blocks for incoming HTTPS requests
server {
    # server block for 'tendaafrica.net', 'www.tendaafrica.net' domains
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tendaafrica.net www.tendaafrica.net;

    # SSL configuration by certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tendaafrica.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tendaafrica.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

The nginx server works very well, but my app is not served as it should be served

Your server block for the api.tendaafrica.net domain, which listens on plain HTTP port 80, immediately redirects to HTTPS port 443. However, you don’t have a server block configured for the api.tendaafrica.net domain on port 443. As a result, any request sent to this domain over port 443 will be handled by the first server block listening on that port (which is a server block for the static.tendaafrica.net domain in your case).

Wow, thank you very much, hadnt noticed that. it has worked
